# Why do my tests not run with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am working on a Symfony 2 project that runs tests with PHPUnit 4.6.2 against a test database. This test database is set up in the config files. Here are the parts regarding the doctrine configuration:

config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:       default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

config_dev.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

config_test.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:     test_sqlite
        connections:
            test_sqlite:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.db
            test_mysql:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: 192.168.56.2
                port: null
                name: myproject_test
                user: root
                password: mysupersafetestpassword
                charset: UTF8
```

As long as I keep `test_sqlite` as the value for `doctrine.dbal.default_connection` in config_test.yml, the tests run fine. However, when I change this value to `test_mysql` I get the following error message on every single one of my tests:

```
Unable to replace alias "doctrine.dbal.test_mysql_connection" with "database_connection".
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:48
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php:63
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler.php:117
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder.php:614
 C:\projects\myproject\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2565
 C:\projects\myproject\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2344
 C:\projects\myproject\app\AppKernel.php:43
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php:141
 C:\projects\myproject\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase.php:33
 C:\projects\myproject\src\mycompany\myprojectBundle\Tests\Controller\SomeControllerTest.php:23
```

What does this error mean and what do I need to change so I can successfully run the tests on the MySQL database?

I guess it is not the sign of a missing MySQL driver as I can e.g. run Symfony commands on the command line just fine against the production DB.

Comment: FYI - you're not running unit tests if you're using your database. You're running functional / integration tests. You should mock your database calls if you are wanting to unit test.

Comment: @Seer You are right, these are actually functional tests. However, they are all run by the same testing framework in a Symfony project. I have changed the wording of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in config_test.yml. The database name is given as parameter `name` but it needs to be `dbname`.

When supplying the parameter `name`, it specifies the connection's name in the YAML file. So the connection was named `doctrine.dbal.myproject_test_connection` and could not be found when Symfony's dependency injection was looking for `doctrine.dbal.mysql_test_connection` as specified in the config file. This resulted in the error shown above.

So the solution is to change the config in config_test.yml to the following:

```
test_mysql:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: 192.168.56.2
    port: null
    dbname: myproject_test
    user: root
    password: mysupersafetestpassword
    charset: UTF8
```